# No network connection w/ Phonegap build app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working to update an older app to a newer version of the phonegap api.  I am struggling with getting network access to work.

I have changed the config.xml to remove the feature blocks and have added the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist.  I have also added the following to the config.xml file.

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

I have also added the content security meta tag to the index file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

The network check reports "unknown" .

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
alert('Connection type: ' + networkState);
```

I have also noticed that the app permissions don't list network access.

Anyone have any ideas as to what would cause this?

Comment: in your **AndroidMainfest.xml** add following line in permission: **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />**

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information` Then `window.Connection` for Checking available internet.

```
var myNetwork=navigator.connection.type;
console.log(myNetwork);
alert(myNetwork);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I already have

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information"  source="npm" />

in my config.xml for phonegap build.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />  Is it showing in androidmanifest file?